# Including wavefront obj models into each other

Tags: wavefront, 3d-model

Is there a way to include several `wavefront obj` files into one?

Friend of mine told me, there is definitely some `include` keyword in obj, which allows me to create obj files like:

```
#room.obj:

include chair.obj
include table.obj

...

v  26.7903 8.1230 26.4282
v  26.3940 8.8766 26.1557
....
```

but I can't find such command in  [documentation](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec).

I want to be able to create such files for combining different others obj files. I do not want to merge two obj files via some 3d editor (which bake geometry together into one).

Is there such command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such command. VRML97 support this via `inlune` command, but not OBJ